# Rails not updating cache when app config is changed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a JavaScript.erb file like:

```
effectiveDate: (new Date("31 Dec <%= APP_CONFIG['year'] %> 23:59:00 GMT")),
```

The problem is that when I change `APP_CONFIG['year']`the JavaScript file never gets updated. I have caching turned off and if I make a direct change in the JavaScript file it updates, and if I check in the rails console it's updated, but the new JavaScript file doesn't get changed.

How can I make this update?

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the app to update the config.

How are you setting the config?

Comment: As mentioned, it gets updated in the rails console (because I am restarting the server). I am just setting the config using a yml file

Comment: Are you sure that it is reading the `APP_CONFIG['year']`? Maybe it is nil.

Comment: Yes, if I for example make some trivial change to the JavaScript file (e.g. multiply by one) than it works. It's just not picking up on the changes

Comment: I mean, are you sure that `APP_CONFIG['year']` is set?